# Is it possible to populate an ObjectListView in a background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker, objectlistview

I have an application in which I **add several thousand items to a listview**. This operation can take a while, but that's fine for the application. However, I would still like to have a marquee progress bar running while the list is being populated, so the user can see something is happening. The **progress bar locks up** since the UI thread is then busy adding the items.

I **tried populating the listview control from within a background worker**, but the progress bar still locked up. It made me understand that since the list control lives in the UI thread, populating it from a background worker does not actually change anything.

Is there a way to still have a progress bar running in this case?

I wondered if it would maybe be possible to have the progress bar running in another thread instead, but I do not know how to do that, or if it is possible.

Here is my code to illustrate (adding 2200 objects):

```
List.SuspendLayout();

StatusText.Text = "Populating the list...";
ProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

List.SetObjects(items);

List.ResumeLayout();
```

I tried using the `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods as well, but it had no noticeable effect (I assume it suspends and resumes the layout too).

Comment: Try using `dispatcher` to update the `listview` data source.

Comment: Have you tried suspending/resuming the layout by calling [`listview1.SuspendLayout()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout) before populating the control, and `listview1.ResumeLayout()` after all items have been added?

Comment: Did you call ListView.BeginUpdate before adding the items?  Also give us an idea what "several thousand" means in real numbers; "several" to me means 2 to 5 thousand, but to you that may be an order or magnitude higher.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Yes, I am calling `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()`.

@TnTinMn: Thanks for the hint, I tried it, but it does not change the fact that the progress bar locks up. I am adding 2250 items to the list, using SetObjects().

I will add some example code how I have it set up.

Comment: @NikhilVartak: That's interesting. Would using a datasource then allow to add the items in a separate thread? Would you have an example, by any chance?

Comment: Alternative method: Manage the `ListView` in Virtual Mode: [ListView.VirtualMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode).  You manage the data (that presumably you already have since you're using it to populate the ListView!) and respond to callbacks from the framework for the data it needs to display, when it needs to display it.  It's generally very fast, and you don't incur overhead of prepopulating the ListView.

Comment: Do you use the [`ObjectListView`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) third-party class? In that case you should probably add to your question the tag [objectlistview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objectlistview).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Yes, I am using ObjectListView. I added the tag to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the pointers you gave me in the comments, I was able to pin down the load delay when populating the list: it was not due to the list control itself. Whenever an item is added to the list, the properties to show in the columns are accessed - as expected. However, some of these properties required additional loading of data, from the database and from the disk.

To solve the issue, I created a separate background worker to initialize the items' internal data cache before adding them to the list. After this, actually displaying the list takes only a couple of seconds at most.

To illustrate:

```
private void PopulateList()
{
    StatusText.Text = "Populating the list...";

    // start the background worker
    PopulateListWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Worker_PopulateList_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // run the data cache initialization
}

private void Worker_PopulateList_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Worker_PopulateList_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List.SuspendLayout();
    List.SetObjects(items);
    List.ResumeLayout();

    progressBar.Value = 0;
    StatusText.Text = "All done.";
}
```